# Sprng Boot @Scheduled task stopped working after cron change

Tags: spring-boot, cron

Spring Boot here. I have a scheduled background task that I kick off every hour on the hour:

```
@Component
public class TokenReaper {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
    public void fire() {
        // Doesn't matter what it does...
    }
}
```

I actually need it to now run *only* at 8:26 AM every day, so only once a day at that time (strange, I know!), so I change the cron expression to:

```
@Component
public class TokenReaper {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 26 8 * * *")
    public void fire() {
        // Doesn't matter what it does...
    }
}
```

After making this change, the task stops running at 8:26 AM, and because of the logs I can't tell when its actually running or if its actually running at all! Can anyone see if my new cron expression is somehow malformed or *not* correctly set to run at 8:26 AM each and every morning?!

Comment: try this  0 26 8 1/1 * ? *

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `?` in your `cron` expression by:

Changing `@Scheduled(cron = "0 26 8 * * *")` into:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 26 8 * * ?")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try, just curious as to why though?! Why does my previous cron (running at top of every hour) not need '?' but my new cron does?

Comment: 1 Seconds 2 Minutes 3 Hours 4 Day-of-Month 5 Month 6 Day-of-Week 7 Year (optional field)

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't answer why an optional field would make the difference though...

Comment: ? ("no specific value") - useful when you need to specify something in one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day of the month (say, the 10th), but I don't care what day of the week that happens to be, I would put "10" in the day-of-month field and "?" in the day-of-week field.

Comment: The optional field (Year) is not added. Instead, the `Day-of-Week` is replaced  from `*` to `?`. Meaning that we don't care when, causing it to repeat every day. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 26 8 * * ?")
```

Cron expression is represented by six fields:

```
second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week
```

**Example patterns**

```
* "0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
* "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
* "0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
* "0 0 8,10 * * *" = 8 and 10 o'clock of every day.
* "0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 and 10 o'clock every day.
* "0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
* "0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```

Comment: Very inconvenient to steal my answer.

Comment: @dryleaf : I know the answer and its takes time to write the proper answer so that user can understand whats's wrong and what should be. I am not interested to  steal anybody's answer. If you think its repeatable information and my answer not useful then, I don't have problem to delete my answer .

Comment: Please go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @dryleaf : do think my answer don't have useful information ?